# How to fill whole screen with Zurb Modal

Tags: css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 modal and would like to adjust the modal in small & medium screen to be such that:

- It fills the whole screen
- When I scroll down in the modal, the background body (origional page) does not scroll down. SO, once I reach the bottom of the modal, it stops scrolling.

I am using the mark up of foundation exactly

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <h2 id="modalTitle">Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with Chrome DevTools and adjust different styles to achieve this.

To do that you need to:

- change width to 100% and add !important to it
- change height to 100% and add !important to it
- set top to 0 and add !important to it

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. This does the job to fill whole screen. But, I am still able to scroll the page while modal is open. How do I disable scrolling page?

Comment: This may have a meaning. Inside body tag, I have a div for modal. Once I open the modal, it changes its class to class="reveal-modal open".

Comment: Uploaded your code into jsFiddle. I've used Foundation 5 docs and it's working perfectly, I can't scroll the page.

Comment: They may have fixed it but the version I am using is not. I am aware it may cause issue to me if I upgrade or something. I found the solution which is setting overflow to the bod to be hidden (overflow:hidden). But I cannot seem to know how to add this property to current page. That is, add a new class to body tag in current page only. Thanks

Comment: Show me your page or once again, add your code to jsFiddle. It's really hard to help you without an example. Anyway, you can use jQuery to set body to "display: hidden" when the Zurb Model is open.